# Solving slave MySQL: waiting for the slave SQL thread to free enough relay log space

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

My slave MYSQL server has stopped syncing with the following status output. Could someone please suggest me a course of action to solve the problem? The database is around 400G so starting from zero is very difficult. MySQL version is 5.5.43-37 on FreeBSD.

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Slave_IO_State: Waiting for the slave SQL thread to free enough relay log space
              Master_Host: 192.168.1.23
              Master_User: repl
              Master_Port: 3306
            Connect_Retry: 60
          Master_Log_File: bin-log.015603
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 1030373074
           Relay_Log_File: relay-log.015629
            Relay_Log_Pos: 804489765
    Relay_Master_Log_File: bin-log.015592
         Slave_IO_Running: Yes
        Slave_SQL_Running: No
          Replicate_Do_DB:
      Replicate_Ignore_DB: cblog_n2
       Replicate_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Ignore_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: cblog_n1.%
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
               Last_Errno: 1049
               Last_Error: Error 'Unknown database 'cr_debug'' on query. Default database: 'cr_debug'. Query: 'CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`192.168.1.23` PROCEDURE `attach`(IN in_debug_id INTEGER)
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
  SET @debug_id = in_debug_id, @timeout = 5;
  DO GET_LOCK(CAST(@debug_id AS char), 5);
END'
             Skip_Counter: 0
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 804489621
          Relay_Log_Space: 10737418784
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File:
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
       Master_SSL_Allowed: No
       Master_SSL_CA_File:
       Master_SSL_CA_Path:
          Master_SSL_Cert:
        Master_SSL_Cipher:
           Master_SSL_Key:
    Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
            Last_IO_Errno: 0
            Last_IO_Error:
           Last_SQL_Errno: 1049
           Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Unknown database 'cr_debug'' on query. Default database: 'cr_debug'. Query: 'CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`192.168.1.23` PROCEDURE `attach`(IN in_debug_id INTEGER)
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
  SET @debug_id = in_debug_id, @timeout = 5;
  DO GET_LOCK(CAST(@debug_id AS char), 5);
END'
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
         Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is my slave config:

```
[client]
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
back_log = 512
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
bind_address = 192.168.1.72     # don't allow remote connections
#tmpdir = /app/mysql/tmpdir
tmpdir = /var/tmp/mysqltmpdir
ft_min_word_len         =3
#core-file
#transaction-isolation = READ-UNCOMMITTED
#old_passwords           =1
connect_timeout         =10
#join_buffer_size        =8M
join_buffer_size        =4M
#key_buffer_size         =7560M
#key_buffer_size        = 25G
key_buffer_size = 5G
max_allowed_packet      =2M
max_connections         =1000
max_connect_errors      =30
myisam_sort_buffer_size =512M
#read_buffer_size        =4M
read_buffer_size        =2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    =4M
#sort_buffer_size        =6M
sort_buffer_size        =2M
#table_cache             =1024
#table_cache             =2024
table_cache             =4048
thread_cache_size       =256
thread_concurrency      =16
wait_timeout            =120
query_cache_size        =12M
max_tmp_tables          =256
#tmp_table_size          =512M
tmp_table_size          =1G
#max_heap_table_size     =512M
max_heap_table_size     =1G
interactive_timeout     =120
query_cache_limit       =8M
query_cache_type        =0
query_cache_size        =128M
#skip-innodb
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
myisam-recover          =FORCE,BACKUP
concurrent_insert       =2
open-files              =30000
#delay_key_write         =OFF
#event_scheduler=ON
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_data_home_dir            = /app/mysql
innodb_data_file_path           = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 5560M
#innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 60G
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 23G
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 110G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
#innodb_log_file_size            = 800M
innodb_log_file_size            = 1256M
#innodb_log_buffer_size          = 32M
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout        = 50
innodb_table_locks              = 0
innodb_support_xa               = 0
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 16
skip-innodb_doublewrite
innodb_buffer_pool_restore_at_startup = 1

#innodb_force_recovery = 4

long_query_time                 = 5
slow-query-log = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
#log-queries-not-using-indexes

## Replication
#log_bin = mysql-bin
#server_id = 1
#binlog_do_db = cblog_n1
#binlog_format = mixed
#log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1

## Master config
#log_bin = /usr/local/mysql/bin-log
#server_id = 1
#expire_logs_days = 8
#binlog_format = mixed

## Slave config
server_id = 2
relay_log = /usr/local/mysql/relay-log
read_only = 1
relay_log_space_limit = 10G
replicate-ignore-db=cblog_n2
replicate-wild-do-table=cblog_n1.%

[mysqld_safe]
core_file_size=unlimited
```

Comment: I would check the logs of the slave.  Did the slave stop for any reason?

Comment: Additional information request from the SLAVE/REPLICA. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS; 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your replication has stopped due to an unknown database cr_debug. Once you clear that up the log space should resolve itself. There are a few ways to resolve it depending on what result you want.

1. If you want that DB to be replicated then create it on the slave with the same table structure as your master. Depending on your situation you may have to do something to make sure it is consistent.
2. If you didn't intend for that database to get replicated then add an "replicate-ignore-db = cr_debug" to your configuration and restart replication. This will cause it to ignore all stataments from that DB in the unprocessed part of the log.

3)If you have a reason to believe that there is just the one statement (or a small handful) going to that DB you can actually just skip the statement using SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1. I don't recommend that though because it is very by hand and rather messy.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added ignore_db for the debug table (the database should have been created on master when we tried to debug a procedure there).

Now I stooped/started slave. It still show the cr_debug error. Should I restart the MySQL?

Comment: Also I now receive a new I/O error:

Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'

Comment: I am sorry for the srd comment. I added a new "replicate-ignore-db=cr_debug" line in config. But the show slave status does not show the cr_debug in replicate-ignore-db list

Comment: When you make a change to the config you have to restart mysql, not just replication. Sorry for that, it's been a while since I actually did this.